# Adding a word in the middle of a sentence with User Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

Can someone help me to make html and javascript about adding a word in the middle of a sentence with user input? Thanks...

Sentence:
Aku sedang [User Input] disekolah.

Input Box | Button to make sentence

the result of the sentence that has been added to the word and entered by the user
ex:

Aku sedang *makan* disekolah.

Comment: Listen to `input.addEventListener("input", cb)` event to see real time text changes. Then change text with `input.setRangeText(...)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setRangeText) when needed

Comment: Homework questions must ask about code that you wrote trying to solve the problem.  This question does not meet the guidelines: [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the html body:

```
    <p>Aku sedang <span id="sentence">_____</span> di sekolah.</p>

    <input type="text" id="userInput"> <button onclick="readMore()">modify</button>
```

then add the script

```
<script>
    function readMore(){
        let word = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = word;
    }
</script>
```

you can read other usability of HTML DOM in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)